# Managed Navigation: only show global navigation and not current navigation

Tags: master-page, managed-navigation, top-link-bar, top-navigation

Pretty much in the title;

I have a set where the some terms have the options

- Show in Global Navigation Menu
- Show in Current Navigation Menu
  checked and others, for multiple reasons, only have the option "Show In Global Navigation" checked. 
  [image]

I have the following code in my masterpage.html, which currently show ALL TERMS irrespective of the selection i mentioned earlier.

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <!--SPM:<Sharepoint:SPNavigationManager  runat="server" QuickLaunchControlId="V4QuickLaunchMenu" ContainedControl="QuickLaunch" EnableViewState="false">-->
                <!--SPM:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="QuickLaunchDataSource">-->
                <!--SPM:<Template_Controls>-->
                <!--SPM:<asp:SiteMapDataSource SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" ShowStartingNode="False" id="QuickLaunchSiteMap" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1025" runat="server"/>-->
                <!--SPM:</Template_Controls>-->
                <!--SPM:</SharePoint:DelegateControl>-->
                <!--SPM:<SharePoint:AspMenu id="V4QuickLaunchMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap" UseSimpleRendering="true" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="1" DynamicHorizontalOffset="0" AdjustForShowStartingNode="true" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2" StaticPopoutImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/menudark.gif?rev=23" StaticPopoutImageTextFormatString="" SkipLinkText="" StaticSubMenuIndent="0"/>-->
                <!--SPM:</Sharepoint:SPNavigationManager>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
```

What i'm after is the ability to show in my top menu just the terms with the "Show in Global Menu" option selected. I have found an answer here [Managed Metadata Global Navigation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174634/managed-metadata-global-navigation)

but i was wondering if there is a more OOTB approach to my solution?

Answer (score 0):

OOTB master pages adhere to the term store "Visibility In Menu" settings. I doubt if you were using a modified/custom master page.

Please check for a Seattle or Oslo master page, your navigation should work as per the term store settings.